# Расширение для firefox с чего начать?

Tags: firefox, addons

Как сделать простое расширение.
Находил старые статьи на хабре, но похоже addon bilder уже не работает.
Есть какая то простая реализация на текущий момент? 
А то на мозила читал, что там нужен НОДЕ..., 
а на хабре вроде писали, что можно самому создавать файлики в блокноте...
Но это все старые статьи от 11 года...
я вот и думаю неужеле так сложно стало...

Мне надо главное это проверка URL текущей страницы. 
и отработка клика, по кнопке (иконке) расширения (замена домена)

Comment: Начните с документации: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/Add-ons

Comment: А нет ссылочки на простой пример реализации расширенияя, рабочий, на сегодняшний момент

Comment: Вобщем остановился на фреймворке канго, сразу делает расширение для 4х браузеров